# How to get current NSView in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm changing my content View from applicaiton

```
[window setContentView:otherView];
[window setContentView:otherView2]; //etc
```

What I need, to be able to get always my current Content View, how I can do that?Something like this
**[window myCurrentContentView];**  or window.view , I couldn't find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[window contentView];
```

should do the trick.

[NSWindow documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/contentView)